# require text field when a drop-down field is selected using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am trying to require the first name field if the a select/drop-down field is selected, using the jQuery validate plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

I know how to accomplish this using a checkbox, but I don't know how to do the same with a drop-down box

You'll see what I am trying to accomplish here http://jsfiddle.net/SupTT/2/

Also, how would I go about requiring the first name field when the drop-down field is not selected, like when a checkbox is not selected: "required: #checkbox-id:unchecked"

Any help is appreciated

Fixed:

```
$("form").validate({ 
 rules: {
   first_name: {
     required: "#fruit:blank"
   }
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT :
Ok all you need is a `depends` inside your required

```
$("form").validate({
rules: {
first_name: {
   required:  {
   depends: function(element){
        return $('#fruit option:selected').text() != '';
         }
      }
     } 
   }

 });
```

......

```
<p>
Fruit <select name="fruit" id="fruit">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="orange">orange</option>
<option value="apple">apple</option>
```

LINK  [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SupTT/3/)

Comment: I may of confused you, I want the first name field required only if the fruit drop-down is selected.

Comment: Thanks, what about if the option was unselected? I tried #fruit option:unselected

Comment: @Brad : Sorry Am confused ..You want a Firstname to be required if option is selected that is done you cancheck the link ...if it is not selected What do you expect please update me.